# Lifecycle of create Object

Tags: javascript

Example

```
class User {
    constructor(firstname, lastName) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    getFullName() {
        return `${this.firstname} ${this.lastName}`;
    }
}


const user = new User('John', 'Doe');
console.log(user.getFullName());


User.prototype.getFullName = function() {
    return 'CRASH!';
}


console.log(user.getFullName());
```

**Why method getFullName changed after create object from class ?**

I suppose after I have created object it's other entity .

Answer (score 2):

According to https://medium.com/backticks-tildes/javascript-prototypes-ee46810e4866 :

> `prototype` is simply a reference to another object and contains
>   common attributes/properties across all instances of the object.
>   When an object gets a request for a property, its prototype will be
>   searched for the property, then the prototype’s prototype, and so on

In your example, when you change the prototype of the User class, it also affects all existing objects.